Fluid Statics (Physics)
When we directly drop a mass into a container of water, the water level rises. In such cases, does pressure vary due to this height variation, everywhere in the fluid?
What cases are to be taken into consideration, if there?
I have been carrying this doubt for a while now, and really need an explanation?

Just rely on Stevino's law
$$P(z) = P_{atm} + \rho g z \ ,$$
with $z$ axis pointing downwards and $z=0$ on the free surface.
When you put a mass in the vessel, the level of the free surface rises w.r.t. the bottom of the vessel, and thus the pressure at the bottom increases as well.
